# How to use Amnesia where (aka Exquisite selector)?

Tags: elixir

I'm using [Amnesia](https://github.com/meh/amnesia) in my project on this way:

```
use Amnesia

defdatabase Database do
  deftable Account, [{:id, autoincrement}, :email, :account_number, :password, :amount],
    type: :set, index: [:email, :account_number] do
      @type t :: %Account{
        id: non_neg_integer,
        email: String.t,
        account_number: String.t,
        amount: integer
      }

      def money_transfer(from_account_number, to_account_number, amount) do
        from_account = Account.where(account_number == from_account_number)
        ...
      end
  end
end
```

In my function `money_transfer/3` I need get accounts on my `Account` table, but the function `where` does not work:

```
warning: variable "account_number" does not exist and is being expanded to "account_number()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  lib/Database.ex:22


== Compilation error in file lib/Database.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/Database.ex:22: undefined function account_number/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    lib/Database.ex:4: (module)
➜
```

How to fix it? I don't know why this error, because the `account_number` is a column declared on `deftable`. I followed the [Amnesia readme](https://github.com/meh/amnesia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reading the tests of Amnesia](https://github.com/meh/amnesia/blob/211d98275c085a9e3049ccb8db8d29f76b3ffbfc/test/amnesia/database_test.exs#L35-L38), I found the solution:

```
defdatabase Database do
  deftable Account, [{:id, autoincrement}, :email, :account_number, :password, :amount],
    type: :set, index: [:email, :account_number] do

    ...

    def get_account_by_account_number(by_account_number) do
      accounts_by_account_number = where(account_number == by_account_number)

      case Amnesia.Selection.values(accounts_by_account_number) do
        [account] -> {:ok, account}
        [] -> {:error, "not found account"}
      end
    end
```

When you are creating a function inside of `detable`, you shouldn't use the
name of table. You should use only the `where` function.

I don't understand very well why of it.